# mongodb 'count' with query is very slow

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

everyone,im use a mongodb 2.4.6 version and in windows 2008 64-bit.

i have a collection that have two million records and need to search and paging in client.

```
db.products.find({"catalogs":1205}).skip().limit() is very fast .
```

but when calculate total record count:

```
db.products.find({"catalogs":1205},{"_id":1}).count() is too slow.

>> 442312 records.

>>[log] Sat Sep 28 00:20:01.566 [conn10] command products.$cmd command: { count: "products", query: { catalogs: 1205.0 }, fields: { _id: 1.0 } } ntoreturn:1 keyUpdates:0 locks(micros) r:460681 reslen:48 460ms
```

this count command elapsed time is `460ms`,is too slow.if we have a lot of request that very terrible.

i created a index for a 'catalogs' field and can't use `$inc` command because query could be very complex.

im googling some like this problem and found this 'count' performance bug already fixed in mongodb 2.4 version.

from http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/2.4-overview/

```
Improvements to count provide dramatically faster count operations. Counting is now up to 20 times faster for low cardinality index based counts.
```

what ways can improve count?thanks.

**update some information**

```
> db.products.getIndexes()
[
    {
            "v" : 1,
            "key" : {
                    "_id" : 1
            },
            "ns" : "products.products",
            "name" : "_id_"
    },
    {
            "v" : 1,
            "key" : {
                    "catalogs" : 1,
                    "created" : -1
            },
            "ns" : "products.products",
            "name" : "catalogs_1_created_-1"
    }
]
```

the query and elapsed time:

```
>db.products.find({"catalogs":1205},{"_id":1}).limit(20)
>>Tue Oct 01 15:39:19.160 [conn2] query products.products query: { catalogs: 1205.0 } cursorid:277334670708253 ntoreturn:20 ntoskip:0 nscanned:21 keyUpdates:0 locks(micros) W:5045 r:1017 nreturned:20 reslen:704 1ms
```

the query exaplin:

```
>db.products.find({"catalogs":1205},{"_id":1}).explain()

{
    "cursor" : "BtreeCursor catalogs_1_created_-1",
    "isMultiKey" : true,
    "n" : 451466,
    "nscannedObjects" : 451466,
    "nscanned" : 451466,
    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 451466,
    "nscannedAllPlans" : 451466,
    "scanAndOrder" : false,
    "indexOnly" : false,
    "nYields" : 2,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "millis" : 2969,
    "indexBounds" : {
            "catalogs" : [
                    [
                            1205,
                            1205
                    ]
            ],
            "created" : [
                    [
                            {
                                    "$maxElement" : 1
                            },
                            {
                                    "$minElement" : 1
                            }
                    ]
            ]
    },
    "server" : "WIN-O47CO6C2WXY:27017"
```

}

Comment: I don't understand why do you collect `_id`s before counting? Why not just use `db.products.count({catalogs:1205})` ?

Comment: hi,`db.products.find({"catalogs":1205}).count()` and `db.products.find({"catalogs":1205},{"catalogs":1}).count()` also slow.thanks

Comment: Could you run it without `find` as I wrote above?

Comment: from log file : [conn1] command products.$cmd command: { count: "products", query: { catalogs: 1205.0 }, fields: {} } ntoreturn:1 keyUpdates:0 numYields: 2 locks(micros) r:1040534 reslen:48 587ms

Comment: @YevgeniyAnfilofyev there is no difference, `count(whatever)` is just a symlink for `find().count()`

Comment: You have an index on catalogs?  And that didn't speed up the count?  Why do you say you "can't use $inc command because query could be very complex" - what does that mean and what does it have to do with the question?

Comment: @Asya Kamsky,yes,i already created a index on 'catalogs'.i can't use `$inc` to pre-calculate because the search query is like this: `select * from table where price>value and created>datetime`.not just catalogs query.i need paging so i must need count how much records to return.

Comment: @zhengchun: Let us make sure. Create Index `db.products.ensureIndex({"catalogs":1})` & then run your count query and let us know the time taken. If still its high you please update the result of this query `db.products.find({"catalogs":1205}).explain()`

Comment: i updated some information.

Comment: the explain that's more relevant is find({catalogs:1205},{_id:0,catalogs:1}) which will make it a covered index query, more analogous to what count does.  Can you also run mongostat at the same time in another window - that will show you what's happening on the system (for example - page faulting?)

Comment: thanks you for answer.i have a question:in mongodb 2.4.6,it's use a `non counting B-Trees`?if yes,maybe i can't optimize this `query count`.in explain function shows a `scanned document' number is too much even if i created index.maybe waiting a feature version fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The reason this count query is not particularly fast is because it has to scan 451466 entries in the index to count up entries.  In other words, your query is not very selective relative to the index and size of the entries that satisfy the query.

Answer (score -2):

`count()` iterates through all the results in cursor before giving a count, that is why its so slow. Use `size()` instead, its pretty fast with respect to `count()`.

Comment: there is no such thing as size() in mongoDB to count documents that fit within a query.